# Почему не срабатывает условие if?

Tags: python, win32gui

почему условие `elif hwnd == old_hwnd:` срабатывает всегда,
а условие `if hwnd != old_hwnd:` не срабатывает вовсе?

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui
import win32process

# Константы
KNAME = 'КОМПАС-3D v'
W = 28
H = 100
IX = 147
IY = 2

# Переменные
topmost = True
kp = np = [-32000, -32000, -30000, -30000]
old_hwnd = 0
old_name = ''


root = tk.Tk()
root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='#F2F2F2', highlightthickness=1,
               highlightbackground='#666666', highlightcolor='#666666')
root.geometry(f'{W}x{H}')


def set_topmost(_value):
    root.attributes('-topmost', _value)


def get_window_rect(_hwnd):
    try:
        return win32gui.GetWindowRect(_hwnd)
    except Exception:
        return np


def update_position(delay=0):
    global cng, hwnd, name, kp, old_kp, old_hwnd, old_name
    while True:
        hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        name = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        old_kp = kp
        this_topmost = root.attributes()[11]

        if hwnd != old_hwnd:
            print('no')
        elif hwnd == old_hwnd:
            a = 1
            # print('yes')

        if KNAME in name:
            set_topmost(True)
            kp = get_window_rect(hwnd)
        else:
            if this_topmost == 1:
                root.lower()
            set_topmost(False)
            kp = get_window_rect(hwnd)

        old_name = name
        old_hwnd = hwnd

        root.geometry(f'+{kp[2]-W-IY}+{kp[1]+IX}')
        root.update()


update_position()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Прекрасно срабатывает при переключении между окнами приложений. Что не так то?

Comment: у Вас linux на борту?

Comment: Какой Linux, если здесь используются модули Win32? Запускал под Windows 7.

Comment: Короче, Atom Runner вообще не выводит ничего в консоль. А вот если запустить из под системы получается 2 раза идет печать change... должна быть один. иногда вообще зависает и ничего не выводит.

Comment: Там наверняка `hwnd == 0` проскакивает, оттого 2 раза.

Comment: Вы правы, но совсем проблему это не решает.